# How can I pre-index parquet datasets using pyarrow 15.0.0?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a parquet dataset stored in an Azure storage container. The parquet files are partitioned such that all files have a path like:

```
exp=AB1234/
    date=2024-02-01/
        speed=100/
            load=5.1/
                data.parquet
```

The whole dataset consists of about 7500 files and around 3 terabytes. New data is only added incidentally, so we can assume that the dataset does not change.

Generally I only have to access small portions of the data and I use pyarrow 15.0.0 in the following code to do so:

```
import adlfs
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
fs = adlfs.AzureBlobFileSystem(
    account_name=account_name,
    credential=credentials
)

filters = [('exp', 'in', ['ZY9876', 'AB1234']), ('speed', '==', '50'), ('temperature', '>', '30')]

dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(container_name,
                            memory_map=True,
                            filesystem=fs,
                            filters=filters,
                            )

df = dataset.read_pandas().to_pandas()
```

When I create an instance of `ParquetDataset`, pyarrow will first crawl through all the parquet files to index all the columns and values of the data. Note that I also apply filters to columns inside the file (i.e., `('temperature', '>', '30')`). The problem is that this takes around 5-10 minutes to construct the dataset. Since the dataset does not change, it should be possible to index all the data once and then just load the index when a part of the dataset is needed. But what is the best solution to do this?

I tried to use a _metadata and _common_metadata file. This is able to create the ParquetDataset very fast (i.e., 3 seconds), but there are some caveats with pyarrow, because I need to pass the argument `use_legacy_dataset=True` to ParquetDataset() to read the metadata files. This will use the old Arrow Dataset API which is not able to filter the columns inside the parquet file. (Besides this, this argument is also deprecated in pyarrow 15.0.0.) It is therefore not desired to use this approach.

What is currently the best solution to pre-index parquet datasets with the available python packages in order to speed up the filtering and loading of the data?

Comment: Have a look at https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#manual-specification-of-the-dataset. With the Datasets API, it's possible to construct a Dataset object from its parts and avoid the discovery step. Additionally, you can cache the Dataset object itself (no matter how you constructed it) and re-use it to avoid needing to re-discover or re-created it.

Answer (score 0):

The [dataset api](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/dataset.html) will use partitioning when filtering.

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

expr = ds.field('exp').isin(['ZY9876', 'AB1234']) & (ds.field('speed') == 50) & (ds.field('temperature') > 30)
dataset = ds.dataset(..., partitioning='hive').filter(expr)
dataset.to_table()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am aware that I can filter on the dataset, but when constructing the dataset with ds.dataset() it will parse through all the files and as far as I understand it is unable to use something like the pre-indexed _metadata files. This takes 5-10 minutes. I am looking for a way to create such an index which can be loaded very fast.

Comment: The filtering will skip unused partitions. In the given example, equality matches on `exp` and `speed` should result in an order-of-magnitude speedup.